# PHPProjekt detecting wrong version of PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to install PHPProjekt on my shared web hosting and for some reason it is detecting wrong version of PHP.

I have configured CPanel to use PHP version 5.3 and other apps work fine and detect the correct version. But for some reason PHPProjekt is not following this setting and including wrong PHP.ini files and detecting a wrong version.

Has anyone came across this situation before? and know how to solve this?

If not are there any alternative open source project management systems (TO DO list, Time Log is must)?

Comment: There must be a setting file in there which tells it where to look for `php.ini`

Comment: I've checked few configuration files but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load `echo phpinfo();` on a .php script, you will see the current PHP version as well as the path to the current php.ini file (Loaded Configuration File).  Update your question with this information and maybe check the php.ini file to confirm that it is the old PHP.  Then you will have to find the 5.3 php.ini, if CPanel successfully installed it.